# Add support to LLRP in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I'm looking  some advices or suggestions as to how add [LLRP](http://www.llrp.org) (Low Level Reader Protocol) support in Netty. I'm going to build a middleware platform to store and manage RFIDs coming from RFID readers and antennas. The reader for example can be something like the Motorola XR480 that already support LLRP.

The idea is to build a Netty-based client-server that comunicate with these readers via LLRP to retrieve the RFIDs readed, process them and store them or send them to a client that has requested them. 
I think Netty would be pretty well suited to this scenario, but I'm open minded to other solutions. :)

There's already a [Java toolkit for LLRP](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/llrp-toolkit), it's easy to add a new tcp protocol support to Netty? Are there any examples to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Netty you can implement any protocol, just implement corresponding handler to serialize protocol messages.
You can look at examples going with Netty.

Comment: Thanks I will look at the examples then. For the record I used Netty before, but I've never had to add support to a new TCP protocol to it before...